# How to restrict edit link being shown in template, based on whether the current user is the owner of a blogpost?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django and attempting to create a a test blog.

Everything is working except I cannot restrict the editing of a blog post to the blog post's owner.

My first attempt was successful, but all I did was "Raised 404" in the view function after comparing whether, or not, the current user was the same as the blog post's owner.

My second attempt involved adding a comparison in the template. But, all that did was remove the edit link for all users, even the owner.

**The template code is below.**

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h3> My Posts </h3>
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_blogpost' %}">Add a new blog post:</a>
</p>
<ul>
  {% for blogpost in blogposts %}     
    <li><strong>{{ user.username }} : {{ blogpost.owner }}</strong>
    <br>
    <strong>{{ blogpost.title }}</strong> - {{ blogpost.date_added }}
    <br>
    {{ blogpost.text }}
    <br> 
    <p>
    {% if user.username == blogpost.owner %}  
      <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_blogpost' blogpost.id %}">edit blog post</a>
    {% endif %} 
    </p>

    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>No posts have been added yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'blogs:new_blogpost' %}">Add a new blog post:</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

Note, I am using Django 1.8. And, for testing purposes, I included both values at the beginning of each list element to confirm which users are the owners of which blogposts.

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your model for blogpost?

Comment: class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """A blog post the user is making"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after this:

```
{% if blogpost.owner.username == request.user.username %}  
    <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_blogpost' blogpost.id %}">edit blog post</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow and I don't know if you could see the model I posted earlier. I believe I have to format the code before posting. Thanks again for your help Will. Question: I was gonna click the check mark to mark it as solved. Is that the way it's done here?

Comment: @earl yes marking the question as answered is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to check if the username of your author is the user visting your website..

**Something like this.**

```
{% if user.username == request.user.username %}  
    <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_blogpost' blogpost.id %}">edit blog post</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I need to compare the user's username with the blogpost owner attribute

Comment: if u supply blogpost owner from views u can compare it with the user's username like demonstrated above

Comment: I'm new to this and trying to figure out how to properly post the code. Thanks for your reply. I used Will's suggestion and it worked. In my template I didn't specify blogpost.owner.username, just blogpost.owner. I believe that's what my problem was.